# Prism Delegate command not enabling button

Tags: wpf, prism

I am trying to enable and disable a button in a WPF (PRISM) user control based on data entered by the user.

```
In the constructor I do
SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnSubmit, CanSubmit);


public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }

private void OnSubmit(object arg)   
{
     _logger.Log(arg.ToString());
}

private bool CanSubmit(object arg) 
{
    return Title.Length > 0; 
}

private string _title="";

public string Title
{
get { return _title; }
set 
{
    if (_title != value)
    {
           _title = value;
       this.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
}
```

I bound the SubmitCommand in the Xaml as below

```
<Button Content="Submit" Width="100" Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TitleText, Path=Text}" />
```

The issue is when title value changes, the button does not get enabled. May be I am missing something. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're needing to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event on your command.  For more details, see http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx

Note that the first link is to an implementation of DelegateCommand, and is probably not what you're actually using.  For the prism DelegateCommand, you simply need to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method when you want to determine whether the button should be reenabled.

Good luck!

Nate

Comment: Thanks Nate. I just had to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
 SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

After:

```
 this.RaisePropertyChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Lloyd. I could not use SubmitCommand directly to raise as SubmitCommand in the above is ICommand. I modified the code to perform what you said using <DelegateCommandInstance>.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();